# Injecting SavedStateHandle on old Koin library versions (example: 2.2.3)

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, koin

I am working on a project that uses Koin in version 2.2.3 where **I cannot upgrade it**.

I would like to know if it is possible to inject `SavedStateHandle` on ViewModels (mainly on **shared** ones) using that version somehow.

Answer (score -1):

The ability was added in version 3.1.3
See this [Change Log](https://github.com/InsertKoinIO/koin/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#:%7E:text=%5BDEPRECATED%5D%20%5Bandroid%5D%20%2D%20by%20stateViewModel()%20is%20deprecated.%20state%20parameter%20is%20not%20needed%20anymore.%20It%27s%20now%20merged%20into%20viewModel()%2C%20to%20inject%20SavedStateHandle) for more info